# Share memory between multiple child processes belonging to same parent

Tags: c, linked-list, shared-memory

I am trying to create Client/Server application based on master/slave architecture. The parent Server is responsible for handling new socket requests from client and uses fork() in which the client interaction happens.

I want to create a Linked List in the application in which the child processes add nodes and it is accessible to every other child. I have tried creating share memory using mmap and shmget but other processes are not able to read the linked list after the first child creates the list.

node structure:

```
struct node{
  char data[1024];
  struct node *next;
};
```

mmap approach:

```
void* create_shared_memory(size_t size){
  int protection = PROT_READ |PROT_WRITE;
  int visibility = MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS;
  return mmap(NULL, size, protection, visibility, -1, 0);
}
```

shmget approach:

```
    void *  my_malloc(int size)
    {
    void * ptr = NULL;
    key_current = key_first++;
    int shm_id;
    if ((shm_id = shmget(key_current, size , IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0) {
        perror("shmget error.");printf("errno= %d EINVAL=%d \n ", errno , EINVAL);
       return NULL;
    }

    if ((ptr = shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0)) == (void *) - 1) {
        perror("shmat error");
        //exit(1);
        return NULL;

    }
    current_index ++ ;
    shm_id_arr[current_index] = shm_id ;
    return ptr;

    }
```

Comment: The same memory is mapped to different virtual addresses in different processes, unless you arrange otherwise, which you should avoid. So pointers do not work; a correct pointer in one process is meaningless in another. So you cannot use linked lists with pointers. You need to design another solution. Using offsets from the start of the shared memory could work.

Comment: One variation on offsets from the start of the shared memory would be to use an array of `struct node` (in the shared memory), with the links being array indices rather than pointers.  Note also that any way around, the node structures themselves need to be in the shared memory.  Even if the shared memory were mapped to the same address in every child, one child still could not use pointers in the shared memory to grant others access to data outside the shared memory.

Comment: The TL;DR answer may be to have the server use threads instead of processes. Then, you don't need to use `mmap` or `shmget` et. al. It makes the shared linked list impl much easier

Comment: @JohnBollinger That would mean predefined number of nodes in the linked list if I'm using array, right?

Comment: @SaadWaseem, it would mean a predefined number of physical node objects, and a predefined *maximum* number of nodes logically in your list.  But those limitations actually arise from the need to store the node objects themselves in the shared memory, not from the specifics of how you describe that to C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating an array with predefined number of `node` elements in the parent process using shared memory and initializing all of the indices before the server listens for client requests and uses `fork()`.

```
#define MAX_NODES 1000  

typedef struct node{
char data[1024];
} node;
  
node *nodes;

void init_array(){

 int id;
 if((id = shmget(12345, sizeof(node)*MAX_NODES , IPC_CREAT | 0666) < 0){
  perror("shmget error");
 }
 nodes = (node*) shmat(id, NULL, 0);

}
```